# O que é injeção de objetos em PHP?

Tags: php, vulnerabilidade, exploit

Eu estava dando uma olhada em artigos da owasp sobre segurança e gostaria de entender o que é o [PHP Object Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/PHP_Object_Injection)
meu inglês não é muito bom então em minha busca encontrei [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199621/php-object-injection) tópico no stackoverflow brasileiro.
Só que mesmo assim não ficou claro para mim como um usuário poderia injetar código PHP em meus projetos, não sabia que usar unserialiaze e serialize em dados que o usuário envia não é uma boa ideia.

Meu projeto está na seguinte situação, o usuário seleciona alguns campos e envia eles eu valido sé de fato é uma url ( porque isso que vai ser serializado ) e depois de validado transformo em base64 para inserir no banco.

Assim:

```
foreach ($Screen as $key => $value) {
if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $Options["screen_".($key+1)] = stringMysql($value);
} else {
    $Erro = "Url inválida!";
    break;
}
```

A função stringMysql escapa os caracteres, antes de inserir no banco de dados. Eu depois dou um unserialize em uma página para exibir as urls.

O meu projeto está vulnerável?

Comment: cara, pra não complicar e ter segurança usa o PDO

Comment: Você consegue me explicar como funciona esse object injection?

A questão de sanitizar os valores do mysql está tudo certinho, todas as querys são higienizadas. Sei que ter uma query preparada é o certo, mas não estou inseguro com isso.